# Regex pattern help wanted

Tags: regex, linux, sed, grep

I have a line that has the follow pattern:

```
A:B=2, G:E=3, N:M=1
AA:BB=20, DG:EE=30 ;;sssddd;; WN:FFM=10
A:dB=200 ssss G:EASD=300 hellp SSASDN:FFFM=100
```

I want to sum all numbers in a line

The output should be

```
2+3+1 = 6

20+30+10 = 60

200+300+100 = 600
```

then I can use the | bc -q to sum them

Comment: Regex doesn't do arithmetic. You'll have to use plain code to add them. You can use regex to find the numbers though.

Comment: I was thinking about getting the numbers into "2+3+1" | bc wchih will return the 6 result

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it with `awk`

```
awk -F"[^[:digit:].]*" '{t=0;for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) t+=$i;print t}'
6
60
600
```

Everything that is not a number is set as a Field Separator

This `FS` should work too: `-F"[=,]"`

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -r 's/[^0-9 ]//g;s/ +/+/g'
```

Output:

```
2+3+1
20+30+10
200+300+100
```

---

```
sed -r 's/[^0-9 ]//g;s/ +/+/g' | bc
```

Output:

```
6
60
600
```

Answer (score 0):

One of these should do whatever it is you really want:

```
$ awk -F'=' -v OFS='+' '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s", $i+0, (i<NF?OFS:ORS)}' file
2+3+1
20+30+10
200+300+100

$ awk -F'=' -v OFS='+' '{sum=0; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) { sum+=$i; printf "%s%s", $i+0, (i<NF?OFS:"=" sum ORS)} }' file
2+3+1=6
20+30+10=60
200+300+100=600

$ awk -F'=' '{sum=0; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) sum+=$i; print sum}' file
6
60
600
```